# Sencha ExtJS Header Title Center Text

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Maybe this is just a case of me over thinking this but I have a panel and I have some text I want to put in the title but I want the text centered. I also want the default background (blue) and text color (white) changed to my custom style. I have successfully been able to change the background and text color but I cannot figure out how to center it in the panel. Here is my code below:

```
{ header: {xtype: 'header', margin:'5', baseCls: 'pnlName-header', title: { baseCls:'pnlName-header-header', text: '<u>Name:</u><br>Josh' }}, xtype: 'panel', flex: 15, layout: { type: 'vbox', align: 'center'}}

.pnlName-header {
color: #FF0000;
font-family: tahoma,arial,verdana,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
text-align:center;
```

}

I am pretty sure it has to be something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

V/R,

Josh

Answer (score 2):

Well after overlooking the obvious as I figured I was doing I found a config called: titleAlign. So I simply set titleAlign: 'center' and that did the trick. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about the same approach you used in header?
http://jsfiddle.net/zk31wo5j/1/

```
 //your panel code
 cls:'center',
 html: 'some text pretty centered'
```

where

```
.center{
text-align:center;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a lot I appreciate it.